# After reinstall or actually demo boot forgot

Tags: login

I can't remember my login or password well I know my password just not my login and I can't seem to get my is to reinstall from my boot CD so I'm in demo plz help so many problems

Answer (score 0):

Using the Demo backup all necessary stuff and then perform a full installation of Ubuntu. That will delete your current Ubuntu.